# Beginner: cakephp 3.6 installing cakedc/users

Tags: php, cakephp, cakedc

I am trying to set up CakeDC/users on a freshly set up App.
I have changed app.php config file to point to correct database (works)
From CMD I have done the following:

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs

php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app MyAppName

cd c:\xampp\htdocs\MyAppName

php composer.phar require cakedc/users
```

Then in bootstrap.php:

```
Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']);
Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true]);
```

(I am not using any social media)

Then in AppcController.php

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', ['enableBeforeRedirect' => false]);
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');                
        $this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth');

    }
```

At the end of all of this, when I run the app (using XAMPP with Apache), I get errors which seem to be saying that cakephp cannot find the plugin controller files as it is looking in the wrong place:

```
Could not load configuration file: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyAppName\config\users.php
Cake\Core\Exception\Exception
Documentation API
If you want to customize this error message, create src\Template\Error\error500.ctp

toggle vendor stack frames
⟩ Cake\Core\Configure\Engine\PhpConfig->_getFilePath
CORE\src\Core\Configure\Engine\PhpConfig.php, line 86
⟩ Cake\Core\Configure\Engine\PhpConfig->read
CORE\src\Core\Configure.php, line 324
⟩ Cake\Core\Configure::load
ROOT\vendor\cakedc\users\config\bootstrap.php, line 22
⟩ Cake\Core\Plugin::{closure}
CORE\src\Collection\CollectionTrait.php, line 51
⟩ Cake\Collection\Collection->each
ROOT\vendor\cakedc\users\config\bootstrap.php, line 23
⟩ include
CORE\src\Core\Plugin.php, line 418
⟩ Cake\Core\Plugin::_includeFile
CORE\src\Core\Plugin.php, line 327
⟩ Cake\Core\Plugin::bootstrap
CORE\src\Core\Plugin.php, line 183
⟩ Cake\Core\Plugin::load
ROOT\config\bootstrap.php, line 211
⟩ require_once
CORE\src\Http\BaseApplication.php, line 145
⟩ Cake\Http\BaseApplication->bootstrap
APP/Application.php, line 37
⟩ App\Application->bootstrap
CORE\src\Http\Server.php, line 121
⟩ Cake\Http\Server->bootstrap
CORE\src\Http\Server.php, line 82
⟩ Cake\Http\Server->run
ROOT\webroot\index.php, line 40
```

It seems to be saying that users.php cannot be found in the app/config folder, but that it is because it is in the config folder for the plugin.

Has anyone met this problem, and can suggest what I am doing wrong.  I am sure it is something simple, and stupid (on my part).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']);` or add your own users.php configuration with overrides if needed.

Check the related docs entry here https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Installation.md#customization

Comment: Hi, Steinkel, I did try it without that line, and it still has the same error.  I have just removed it, and it is still not working.  Not sure what you mean by teh second bit about adding my own users.php config... is there an example somewhere?

Comment: There's an example on the configuration page of the documentation linked to above. And there's a more complete example (specifically, all the default values) in their code.

Comment: Sorry to both Greg and Steinkel.  I have been through all the documents I can find on CakeDC/users - but everything I tried fails.
I am new to using 3.x, and I thought that the features provided by CakeDC/Users would be great.. but I also thought that setting up a plugin (in the vendors folder) would be straightforward.
My understanding is that all the files for plugin are held in appropriate folder in  vendors folder (in this case cakedc/users) and that cakephp would "join" them up with rest of my app.  So I have not got any users files in my main app - no templates, controllers, models.

Answer (score 0):

As an example you can copy the original user.php

```
cp -i vendor/cakedc/users/config/users.php config/
```

In my bootstrap.php I have this

```
Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']);
Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true]);
```